Is there a way to add an object to a vector via the constructor body?
So I'm new to c++ and programming in general, and in some of my assignments I need to store objects that I create in a vector and I always used this method:
std::vector<Class_Name> Classes;
Class_Name c1,c2,c3,c4;

Classes.push_back(c1);
Classes.push_back(c2);
Classes.push_back(c3);
Classes.push_back(c4);

But it looks kind of ugly.
I then found out that this method is pretty inefficient and creates an unnecessary copy of the object and I then found out about emplace_back.
Got to this:
std::vector<Class_Name> Classes;
Classes.emplace_back(args);

This is nice and all but I was thinking if there was a way to create an object and, with the help of some magic in the constructor body, have it be put into a vector.
Something like this(?):
class Class_Name{
...
std::vector<Class_Name> Classes;
public:
Class_Name(args) {Classes.push_back(c1)} // just imagine c1 is the object to be
...
};

So that when I create an object in main(), it will automatically store it in the "Classes" vector.
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
Class_Name c1,c2,c3;
// then if I run a ranged for loop it will print what I wrote in a print() func
for(auto a : Classes)
a.print();
}

In short, is emplace_back the most efficient method and, if someone understood what I was trying to show with the constructor, is it possible to do my example/is it worth it?

std::vector<Class_Name> Classes(4); or std::vector<Class_Name> Classes = { {}, {}, {}, {} };?

Since your vector has objects, not pointers, you can't do that "in the constructor" -- your constructor will basically create the object that it was told to create, plus an additional one in the vector. So, you produce two for each order of one... which, come to think of it, would even create an infinite recursion, so forget what I just said. And generally you want to be careful with the pointers, because you still have to manage the lifetime of the object you're creating... so that's not really a good workaround either.

I hope I understood you correctly, as I understood Even if it were possible to do as the example you mentioned, it would not solve the problem of the double copying,
Because when you called the push_back function and sent it an object, then the object would go through the copy constructor to get to the function,
What's more, if you don't plan to use objects outside the vector, you don't have to assign pointers to them, you can define them like this:
std::vector<Class_Name> Classes;
Classes.push_back(Class_Name());
Classes.push_back(Class_Name());
Classes.push_back(Class_Name());
Classes.push_back(Class_Name());

In conclusion:
If you want to use objects outside the vector then use push_back() so that a copy is created for you - and then not every change you make to one of the objects will also affect the one in the vector,
But if you don't plan to use objects outside the vector then use Emplace_back(), and of course you also don't need to assign pointers but generate the objects inside the call to the function:    Classes.push_back(Class_Name());
If anyone disagrees with me I would love to hear more opinions.

I see, this cleared up most of my confusion, thank you for the answer!
I didn't know about this alternative way of defining objects via push_back.
So in this example does the push_back operate in a way similar to emplace_back? Since you are not creating an object, THEN storing it in a vector and/or does it still make a copy?
If it does make a copy, is it not better to use emplace_back? in the instance that I don't use the objects outside of storing them in a vector.
Thank you again for the help.

I edited the answer. If something is still not clear - ask and I will be happy to answer.
